# Response.AddHeader in an ascx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, ascx

Is it possible to use the Response.AddHeader particularly Im trying to use the "Refresh" of it. **I need it to pause before it redirects** but the place where the code is being ran is in a ASCX in the codebehind. It does nothing when I have the following in my Codebehind:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "6;URL=Default.aspx");
```

Any way I can redirect a user in the codebehind on a ascx page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why that isn't working for you - it seems to be the right syntax to add the redirect to your HTTP header, and it works for me on several browsers. To debug this, you can run Fiddler or a similar tool to see the full HTTP response, and see if it's not making it to the header.

You may want to try reformatting slightly - the examples I've seen have a space between the semi-colon and the `url`, and `url` keyword in lower-case. I doubt this is the problem, but worth a try, if it's failing on specific browsers:

```
Refresh: 0; url=http://www.example.com/
```

An alternative approach, maybe easier to debug, is to use a meta tag instead of HTTP header, so it actually shows up in the markup.  Something like:

```
var metaControl = new HtmlMeta
  {
    Content = "2;url=http://webdesign.about.com/",
    HttpEquiv = "refresh"
  };
Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaControl);
```

This will add a `<meta>` tag to your `<head>` section, which should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
if(today == "Friday")
{
   Response.Redirect("destination.aspx")
}
```

If that doesn't work, please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Response.Redirect wont work for my situation, I clearly stated that I need to pause before it redirects, and the only way to pause with Response.Redirect is by using something like Thread.Sleep which is just bad programming. That is all I am looking for is a way to redirect a user from an ascx file.